# How to get user's published / pending post status only (Wordpress and PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

**In one sentence: when a free user tries to edit his published post, I would like to use "gets post status" for publish or pending only so i can hide some divs.**

My coding skill is very basic but i am working on a Wordpress website where people can create custom posts.

There are two types of membership : free or premium. I am trying to prevent free members from editing specific parts of their post once their post is published or pending (if possible). They can edit when in draft or have premium.

It might be important to note that users create posts via a specific page i created ( id = 6), not through wp backend.

Right now the code below seems to work in both published and draft posts. I would like the code to work only for the user's published or pending post.

Here is the code im trying to work with :

```
<?php if (($usermeta['_checkbox_premium_user'][0] != "yes") && ($_GET['edit'] == 'true') && ( get_post_status ( $ID ) == 'publish' )) { ?>

<div class="mydiv">content to show</div> <?php } else { ?>   <div class="mydiv2">content to hide</div> <?php } ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: you want to hide the content editor after the user published their post?

Comment: Dolatabadi, i can hide #mydiv2 by adding style="display:none;" to the div but my problem is with the php code on top which is probably not written the correct way. The goal is to get status of the post the user is trying to edit and make sure its current status is published before i can hide the div.

Comment: We can consider #mydiv2 as the editor as well.

Comment: Still reading the question, but in your php example, should your $_GET['pid'] have the '== true ' statement as well? Since php isn't not reading the pid AND edit the same way in that line of code.

Comment: I tried  $_GET['pid'] with '==true' statement as well but nothing changed. When user clicks edit on one of his posts it looks like this on the browser : domainurl/create-a-new-post/?pid=376&edit=true

Comment: I am thinking maybe since the page /create-a-new-post/ has an ID as well and is published it will always return a publish status even when editing a draft. If this is true, a possible solution could be trying to exclude that page id (6) from the php code. Something i dont know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out :

```
<?php if (($usermeta['_checkbox_premium_user'][0] != "yes") && ($_GET['edit'] == 'true') && (get_post_status ( $_GET['pid'] ) == 'publish')) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**user can view pending post wordpress**

```
   function allow_pending_listings($qry) {
        $status = get_post_status ( $_GET['eid'] );
        if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $edit_data = get_post($_GET['eid']);    
         if (!is_admin() && $edit_data->post_author == $userdata->ID && $status !='publish' ) {
        $qry->set('post_status', array('publish','pending','draft'));
         }
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts','allow_pending_listings');
```